# Issues Converting DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, localization

I'm working with localization. I have my CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture set to "es", which has the dd/mm/yyyy format for the DateTimes.

Running this command returns an object reference error:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("28/07/2014");
```

It works perfectly fine in my environment, but the error happens on a server2008 r2 OS with the Region and Language set to English(United States). Theoretically, that shouldn't matter since I am setting the culture. I am setting the culture before the screen opens and have other localized things working just fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on something I can look in to? I'm out of ideas. I also tried sending the DateFormatInfo of "es" to force it to work, but that didn't go through either.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("28/07/2014","dd/MM/yyyy",Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I've seen this solution elsewhere, but I can't assume it is going to be "dd/MM/yyyy". It just is in this scenario. I can run a test with that to see if it works if you think it would be helpful in determining why I'm getting the error versus not in my dev environment.

Comment: What are the possible inputs?

Comment: Any date. It will have already been validated and it will be in whichever format the current culture is in.

Comment: Will you know the culture it is in?

Comment: Yes, I tried sending it the DateTimeFormatInfo and that didn't work. I also went ahead and tried the ParseExact manually putting in "dd/MM/yyyy" and it got the same reference error. I'll update if I find anything new.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.Text = String.Format(DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString(), "dd-MM-YYYY");
```

Are you referring to a string format?